# LargeTitle doesn't show at first when tableView has top inset

Tags: swift

I am using LargeTitle in navBar, I have my tableView at viewController, but when I set top inset to tableView, largeTitle is not showing at first

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: [yourTableViewTopInset + 1]), animated: false)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).